# how to make request body in gorm for Association belongs to and has one

Tags: postgresql, go, struct, go-gorm, go-gin

I have **People** and **Data** ,  where **People** *has one* **Data** and **Data** *belongs to* **People**
how to make a request body JSON for that Association in go gin? I am using gorm for this case,
the documentation of gorm is not clear for me for this case, 
i was supposed  like

```
func CreateTodo(db *gorm.DB) func(c *gin.Context) {
    var person Person
    var data Data 

    c.bindJSON(&Person)
    c.bindJSON(&Data)

    db.create(&Person)
    db.create(&Data)

    c.JSON(200, gin.H{ result : []interface{person, data})
}
```

```
type (
    Data struct {
        ID          uint `gorm:"auto_increment"`
        PersonID    uint
        Person      *Person `gorm:"foreignkey:PersonID;association_foreignkey:id"`
        Address     string
        Languange   string
    }

    Person struct {
        gorm.Model
        Email    string `gorm:"type:varchar(100);unique_index;not null"`
        Password string `gorm:"type:varchar(100);not null"`
        Role     string `gorm:"size:30;not null"`
        DataID   uint
        Data     *Data `gorm:""foreignkey:DataID;association_foreignkey:id"`
    }
)
```

I am sure it will not make the *person_id* and *data_id* for **FK**
what I ask, how I can make the request body for that Association until those request created with FK itself ? should I create then update again for *person_id* and *data_id* after it created ??

Answer (score 1):

Gorm will do almost everything for an association link. It seems that "DataID" in your Person struct is useless. See the code below for an example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/sqlite"
)

type (
    Data struct {
        ID        uint `gorm:"auto_increment"`
        PersonID  uint
        Person    *Person `gorm:"foreignkey:PersonID;association_foreignkey:id"`
        Address   string
        Languange string
    }

    Person struct {
        gorm.Model
        Email    string `gorm:"type:varchar(100);unique_index;not null"`
        Password string `gorm:"type:varchar(100);not null"`
        Role     string `gorm:"size:30;not null"`
        Data     *Data  `gorm:""foreignkey:PersonID;association_foreignkey:id"`
    }
)

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open("sqlite3", "test.db")
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }
    db.LogMode(true)
    defer db.Close()

    // Migrate the schema
    db.AutoMigrate(&Person{}, &Data{})

    data := &Data{
        Address:   "Shanghai,China",
        Languange: "Chinese",
    }
    person := &Person{
        Email: "zhjw43@163.com",
        Data:  data,
    }
    db.Save(person)

    db.DropTable("data", "people")
}
```

Comment: should i not using `db.Model(&models.Data{}).AddForeignKey("person_id", "people(id)", "CASCADE", "CASCADE")` because when i using this, it not created the data on my database, after i comment it, it was created

Comment: will that generate automaticall person_id and data_id ??

Comment: ref [here](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/master/scope.go#L1248) for details, it seems like `AddForeignKey` add foreign_key explicitly to database( such as pg or mysql). As far as I know, foreign_key has some constraints, which may make your problems. The person_id and data_id are defined in your struct, which are common fields but you can add foreignKey on them.

Comment: u mean, i should eat another name for it because person_id and data_id already exist ? can u give me example and edit your answer  please, i tried with db.Model(&Person).Related(&Data) to find, but not success